# export declare type ResourceType = Lowercase<Protocol.Network.ResourceType>, Error building nodejs app with Puppeteer and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer, typescript-typings

I'm working on a nodejs project to generate PDFs using **Puppeteer** in server side. In there I'm using typescript and current version of the Puppeteer is 8.0.0(provides it's own type definitions).

But in the build process, getting the below error

[image]

In the **types.d.ts** file also I can see **Lowercase** is not defined.

Does anyone knows what is the error?

Comment: Make sure that your typescript package is up to date.  The `Lowercase` type was not added until [version 4.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html)

Comment: Thanks, after upgrading to the  latest typescript version it worked.

Answer (score 6):

just change your typescript version to "typescript": "^4.2.3" in package.json file.